# MySQL php get items from database and store in XML (Duplicated items)

Tags: php, mysql, xml

First of all here is my code , and it works, just has a major flaw in it which I do not know how to fix. I have cleared the code of all elements except the ones that cause the issue for better reading purposes.

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = DB_USERNAME;
    $password = DB_PASSWORD;
    $database = DB_DATABASE;

    // Start of table variables

    // End of table variables
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    $sql = "SELECT pd.name as product_name, p.model as product_model, p.quantity as product_quantity, cd.name as category_name , p.product_id as product_id , p.price as product_price , m.name as product_manufacturer ,  p.image as product_image , pd.description as product_description
            FROM product p
            INNER JOIN product_description pd ON pd.product_id = p.product_id
            INNER JOIN product_to_category ptc ON ptc.product_id = p.product_id
            INNER JOIN category_description cd ON cd.category_id = ptc.category_id
            INNER JOIN manufacturer m ON m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id
            WHERE pd.language_id = 2 AND cd.language_id = 2 AND p.status = 1 AND p.product_id = p.product_id AND p.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id";

    $conn->set_charset('utf8mb4');
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $xml = new XMLWriter();

    $xml->openURI("php://output");
    $xml->startDocument();
    $xml->setIndent(true);

    $xml->startElement('products');

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($product = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $product_id             = $product["product_id"];
            $product_category       = $product["category_name"];

                $xml->startElement("product");

                    $xml->startElement("itemid");
                        $xml->writeRaw($product_model);
                    $xml->endElement();


                    $xml->startElement("category");
                        $xml->writeCDATA($product_category);
                    $xml->endElement();
                    //end

                $xml->endElement();

        }
    }else{

    }

    $xml->endElement();

    $xml->flush();

?>
```

When I run my code everything start and it generated and XML structure. the XML that I posted below is of the first product which has the ID of **23793**

The code duplicated my **products** 3 times because every product has a Main category  **Games**, sub-category **PS3** and sub-sub-category **Fighting**

```
<product>
    <itemid>pls-23793</itemid>
    <category>
    <![CDATA[ Games ]]>
    </category>
</product>
<product>
    <itemid>pls-23793</itemid>
    <category>
    <![CDATA[ PS3 ]]>
    </category>
</product>
<product>
    <itemid>pls-23793</itemid>
    <category>
    <![CDATA[ Fighting ]]>
    </category>
</product>
```

These are all stores in the Database like this

**Example:**

This is the INNER JOIN `INNER JOIN product_to_category ptc ON ptc.product_id = p.product_id`

product_to_category structure:

```
product_id | category_id

   23793   |  58  (This is the ID of Games)
   23793   |  135 (This is the ID of PS3)
   23793   |  777 (This is the ID of Fighting)
```

How Can I make it so that it doesn't echo out the same product 3 times but for product 23793 get thsese categories like Games > PS3 > Fighting

I tried doing a foreach loop on the categories but I don't think its from the php but the issue comes from the MySQL Select code

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `GROUP_CONCAT` to your query

```sql
SELECT 
    pd.name as product_name, 
    p.model as product_model, 
    p.quantity as product_quantity, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(cd.name SEPARATOR ' > ') as category_name, 
    p.product_id as product_id, 
    p.price as product_price, 
    m.name as product_manufacturer,  
    p.image as product_image, 
    pd.description as product_description
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_description pd ON pd.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN product_to_category ptc ON ptc.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN category_description cd ON cd.category_id = ptc.category_id
INNER JOIN manufacturer m ON m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id
WHERE 
    pd.language_id = 2 
    AND cd.language_id = 2 
    AND p.status = 1 
    AND p.product_id = p.product_id 
    AND p.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Comment: Can you explain more what a GROUP_CONCAT is please?

Comment: In combines groups of data (rows) into single strings, basically. [This page](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) might be easier to follow. But regardless, wondering if the new query helped or not?

Comment: You'll need to add a GROUP BY p.product_id to the query too.

Comment: Thank you @rob - I tested by selecting having a single product ID in my where clause and over looked the GROUP BY :)

Comment: @LucasKrupinski Worked like a charm, you sir deseve a medal, amazing

Can you also explain the GROUP BY synax?

Comment: It won't let me give you the bounty, I will give it to you in 22 hours

Comment: In lieu of a medal, you can just mark that I solved so I get some points :). GROUP BY just groups multiple identical rows into a single row. I'd give you a link but I just got in the car!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select case when@var <> brand then @Var :=p.product_id end as product_id
(
SELECT pd.name as product_name, p.model as product_model, p.quantity as product_quantity, cd.name as category_name , p.product_id as product_id ,     p.price as product_price , m.name as product_manufacturer ,  p.image as product_image , pd.description as product_description
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_description pd ON pd.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN product_to_category ptc ON ptc.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN category_description cd ON cd.category_id = ptc.category_id
INNER JOIN manufacturer m ON m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id
WHERE pd.language_id = 2 AND cd.language_id = 2 AND p.status = 1 AND     p.product_id = p.product_id AND p.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id
GROUP BY p.product_id
)
as foo
cross join (Select @var := '') as foo2
```

You can add the additional fields that you need in the top select, but this will essentially eliminate the duplication of products in the first field.